# Let $I$ and $J$ be prime ideals. Then is $I\cdot J=I\cap J$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I$ and $J$ be two prime ideals in a commutative ring $R$ with unity. Is it true that $I\cdot J=I\cap J$? I know that it is not true if the ideals under consideration are not prime: consider the ideals $(6)$ and $(8)$ in the ring $\Bbb{Z}$. Their intersection is $(24)$, but their product is $(48)$.

However, I cannot think of a counter-example in the case of prime ideals.
I tried proving the assertion in the following way: We know that $I\cdot 
J\subset I\cap J$. Hence, we shall try and prove the inclusion in the other direction.

> Let $a$ be an element in $I\cap J$ that is not present in $I\cdot J$. Then $a^2\in I\cdot J$. How will this then go on to prove that $a\in I\cdot J$?

Comment: What if $I=J$?  ,

Comment: @Timkinsella- Ah. Thanks. That clears up a lot of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has $I\cdot J=I\cap J$ if the $I$ and $J$ are coprime ideals, i.e. if  $I+J=R$. In general, one can only say $\;I\cdot J\subseteq I\cap J$.

This is the basis of the *Chinese remainder theorem*: if $I$ and $J$ are coprime ideals then $I\cdot J=I\cap J$, and 
$$R/(I\cdot J)=R/I\times R/J.$$

Comment: But what about $(x),(y)\subset \Bbb{C}[x,y]$? these are not co-prime. However, $(x).(y)\subset (x)\cap (y)$

Comment: $xy$ is in the second ideal too!

Comment: I@Ayush Khaitan: I said the general assertion was $\cdot J\subseteq I\cap J$. How does it conrtradict your claim?

Comment: Ah okay. I thought you meant this was true iff and only if $I+J=R$. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Could you, just for the sake of completeness, give an example of two prime ideals such that $I.J\neq I\cap J$?

Comment: Just take a local noetherian ring $R$ which is not a field, with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$, and set $I=J=\mathfrak m$. Then $I\cdot J=\mathfrak m^2$, and $I\cap J=\mathfrak m$. By *Nakayama's lemma*, $\;\mathfrak  m^2=\mathfrak m$ would imply $\mathfrak m=0$, in other words $R$ would be a field.

Comment: Other example: let $V$ a discrete valuation domain, with uniformisingg parameter $\pi$. All ideals in $V$ have the form $(\pi ^r$  for some $r\ge 0$?. Consider the ideals $I=(\pi^r)$ and  $J=(\pi^s)$ $\;1\le r<s$. Then $J\varsubsetneq I$, so $I\cap J= J=(\pi^s)$, but $I\cdot J=(\pi^{r+s})\varsubsetneq J$.

Answer (score 2):

This will be true if $I + J = R$. To see why, note that if $I$ and $J$ are coprime ideals, then $1 = x + y$ for some $x \in I$, $y \in J$. Consider $z \in I \cap J$. Then

$$
z = z \cdot 1 = z \cdot (x+y) = \underbrace{z}_{\text{in $J$}} \cdot \underbrace{x}_{\text{in $I$}} + \underbrace{z}_{\text{in $I$}} \cdot \underbrace{y}_{\text{in $J$}} \in I \cdot J
$$

Hence $I \cap J \subseteq I \cdot J$. In general, $I \cdot J \subseteq I \cap J$, from which equality follows.

However, this condition $I + J = R$ is not absolutely necessary. For example, consider $R = \mathbb{Z}/6$ with ideals $I = J = (2)$. Then $I \cdot J = (2) = I \cap J$, even though $I + J \ne R$.